# Current industry standard with regards to C macros

Tags: c, coding-standards, macros, industry-standard

I have read from several authors that macros in C should be avoided whenever possible, and use `inline` functions instead. It's true that `inline` only 'requests' the compiler to replace the function call by 'expand' the function body in the calling place, however my understanding is that, if a modern C compiler 'doesn't want to inline' a function, probably it's because it shouldn't be.

However, I still see an intensive use of macros and `#ifdef` etc. directives in 'modern' open source projects, such as `FreeRTOS`, `Zephyr` and many others.

Does this mean that the industry has reconsidered its position with regards to macros? Is there any good reason to use macros instead of inline functions?

Comment: There is no "industry standard" for this.  It's a guideline based on real-world experience.  Examples of proper "industry standards:" the HTML5 Standard, and ECMA-262 (the JavaScript Specification).

Comment: See [this draft](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/bismon-chariot-doc.pdf) report listing several of them. Look into [MISRA C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MISRA_C) as an example. Read of course the [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) C11 standard. Study for inspiration the source code of [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) or of the [Linux kernel](http://kernel.org/)

Comment: Look also for inspiration into the source code of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), of [GTK](http://gtk.org/) or of [NWCC](http://nwcc.sourceforge.net/) and be aware of [GNU autoconf](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/).

Comment: Read about [*Inovking GCC*](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) and be aware of the `-flto -O2` options to `gcc`

Answer (score 4):

You see an absolute rule, and things don't work that way. You also seem to be focussed on macros vs. inline functions which is very rarely the question.

Macros can be extremely useful if you know how to use them. They can also be anything from misleading to dangerous if you don't know what you're doing.

I haven't used the two projects that you mention, but I have used others, and their use of macros is generally very reasonable and appropriate. The stupid macro uses what we are warned not to use are very rare. "Use inline functions instead of macros" is a bit outdated - I'd suggest using real functions instead of macros for that and only use macros when performance is absolutely critical (which is rare).

Answer (score -3):

Common usages of macros

#### Macro for defining constants

```
// Bad
#define PI 3.14

// Good
const double PI = 3.14;
```

Always use `const` instead. This makes sure that you explicitly type your constant.

#### Function-like macro

If you can use function to achieve what you want, always use a function. Explicitly declaring this function `inline` is not necessary. As you correctly noted, the `inline` keyword does not really tell compiler to inline the function. It just puts a restriction on the function that you can not take address of that function. Practically, this allows you to put the function body in the header file without compiler giving you a redefinition error when you include this header in multiple C files.

#### Where is a function-like macro actually useful?

There are some cases where you want to remove duplication of certain code and a function-call does not let you achieve what you want.

For example a logging macro that prints line number and function name.

```
// Macro definition in some header file.
#define MYLOG(fmt, args...) \
fprintf(stderr, "%s:%d, " fmt "\n", __func__, __LINE__, ##args);

// Usage
{
...

MYLOG("Hello World %d", 1234);
...
}
```

This creates a function-like macro that prints your message along with the function name and line-number from the source file. As an exercise try to see if you can avoid using a macro and achieve the same functionality.

P.S. It's not possible (at least in C or C++).

#### Macros as compile-time flags

This is a very genuine and justified usage of macros. If you want to do selective compilation based on some conditions (which come from either compiler command line or a Makefile), there is no other way than to use macros. However, even in this scenarios macros should be used sparingly. Having too many #ifdefs in your code makes it difficult to read. As much as possible, I would do this selective compilation by moving code to separate files.

Comment: No, there are cases for coding `#ifdef PI`. Look into the source code of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) for examples and see [GNU autoconf](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/)

Comment: There may be existing code that uses this pattern and but for new code there is very little justification of #defining constants.

Comment: There are *lots* of good reasons for `#define`ing constants. Look into the source code of the [Linux kernel](http://kernel.org/) as a counter example, and also inside the source code of [SBCL](https://sbcl.org/) or of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)

Comment: See my edit regarding compile-time flags. When I mean constants, I do not mean compile-time flags used to selectively compile some code. If you want to point me to some code, at least point to a file where I can read something. Giving "entire" linux kernel as an example, does not really help in the argument. Can you give me an example of some justification that you are talking about, so we can have meaningful discussion?

Comment: Please study carefully the source code of the Linux kernel,  and what the `make menuconfig`  command does there. Spend a few days in compiling the linux kernel from source code. Also, compile and study the source code of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)

Comment: Read also [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) and [this draft](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/bismon-chariot-doc.pdf) report

Comment: Also study the source code of [L4 microkernels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L4_microkernel_family) and of [GNU hurd](https://www.gnu.org/software/hurd/) and of [GTK](https://gtk.org/)

Comment: A good reason to use #define for constants in C is when the compiler needs to use the value (for example, as an array size). In C, `const` does not mean constant, but rather read-only and a `const` variable can't be used where a true constant is required.

Comment: `const double PI = 3.14;` restricts `PI` to the precision of  `double`.  `#define PI 3.14` allows `PI` to have the precision of `long double` when `FLT_EVAL_MODE = 2`.  Not functionally equivalent code between the macro and `const`.  Best use depends on case.

Comment: @PunitSoni.   Suggest you look at the output of `find /usr/include -type f -exec grep -H _MAX {} \;`